# SQL Server Stored Procedure to Select/Update/Return

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a SQL Server stored procedure that selects the top row from a table, updates a column in that row, and then returns this row with the changes.

For example:

1. `row = SELECT TOP 1 FROM Requests`
2. `UPDATE Requests SET row.Locked = True`
3. `RETURN row`

I can't seem to get this right..can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Top 1 is determined how/ Order By what?

Comment: @Jeff O - Top 1 is determined by a few WHERE clauses...basically I am selecting TOP 1 WHERE Locked = False

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
update top(1) Request
set Locked = 1
output inserted.*
where Locked = 0
```

A version when you need order by to get the row you want to modify. 
Here you will set `Locked=1` for the highest `DateField` value where `Locked = 0`

Test data

```
create table Request(ID int, Locked bit, DateField datetime)
insert into Request values (1, 0, '20010101')
insert into Request values (2, 0, '20010102')
insert into Request values (3, 0, '20010103')
```

Update statement with cte

```
;with cte as 
(
  select *,
    row_number() over(order by DateField desc) as rn
  from Request
  where Locked = 0
)
update cte
set Locked = 1
output inserted.ID, inserted.Locked, inserted.DateField
where rn = 1
```

Result

```
ID          Locked DateField
----------- ------ -----------------------
3           1      2001-01-03 00:00:00.000
```

Or you could do this if you want to use `inserted.*` instead of specifying the fields in output clause.

```
update Request
set Locked = 1
output inserted.*
from Request as r
  inner join
    (select ID, row_number() over(order by DateField desc) as rn
     from Request
     where Locked = 0) as rs
    on r.ID = rs.ID and
       rs.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Had to give the answer to the earlier post but your answer also helped.

Comment: @thiag0 - Added a version where you can use `order by` to get the row you want to update.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an OUTPUT clause:

```
 DECLARE @Results TABLE (SomeField INT)

 UPDATE TOP (1) Requests
 SET Locked = 1
 OUTPUT inserted.SomeField INTO @Results (SomeField)

 SELECT * FROM @Results
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Is there a way to declare that table variable so it matches the table I am querying without having to explicitly setup the columns?

Comment: @thiag0 - You do not need the table variable. The output statement without `into` will return the rowset to the client.

Comment: Cool, that worked.  One more question...I was able to add my WHERE clauses after the OUTPUT statement, however I could not add an ORDER BY.  Is it possible to use an ORDER BY when using OUTPUT?